# Setting second x-axis using set_xticklabels based on other subplot of same figure gives Text(X, u'X') representation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to set a second x-axis using xticklabels from another subplot of the same figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax1.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])
ax2.plot([4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5])
ax3 = ax2.twiny()
ax3.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels())
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot however gives me a textual representation of the matplotlib.text object:

[image: xticklabel representation]

any ideas what's going wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`get_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=get_xticklabels#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels) returns a list of [`Text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) objects but [`set_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=get_xticklabels#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) expects a list of strings. As you have it written, you're simply getting the text representation of the `Text` objects rather than the text of the labels themselves. You'll need to extract the list of labels from the list of `Text` objects prior to calling `set_xticklabels`

Now how you get a list of strings depends on whether the xtick labels on `ax1` are the automatically assigned tick labels or whether they custom strings. If you are using the automatic labels, then you'll need to get the [`Formatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting) for the axis and convert the ticks to strings to pass to `set_xticklabels`

```
# Get the formatter which determines the way that they are displayed
formatter = ax1.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter()

# Convert each xtick to it's string representation using the formatter
labels = [formatter.format_data(x) for x in ax1.get_xticks()]

# Update the labels on your other axes
ax3.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

If they are already custom strings then you can do the following:

```
ax3.set_xticklabels([t.get_text() for t in ax1.get_xticklabels()])
```

You can also specify the format yourself

```
ax3.set_xticklabels(['%d' % x for x in ax1.get_xticks()])
```

Comment: thanks, it's getting there!
the formatter gives me a string-representation in scientific notation, i.e. 1e5, 5e5 etc. how can I change the format to the normal integer representation?

Comment: @MischaObrecht Updated with an example of that

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the purpose of this ticklabel swapping is, it might be sufficient to copy the ticks themselves, instead of the ticklabels.

```
ax3.set_xticks( ax1.get_xticks() )
```

This might be especially appropriate if at the same time you also copy the axes limits

```
ax3.set_xlim( ax1.get_xlim() )
```